# Что происходит после закрытия окна в qt при помощи функции close()?

Tags: c++, qt

Что происходит после закрытия окна в qt при помощи функции close()?

Comment: Жизнь продолжается...

Comment: @vp_arth   никакой метод из окна,которое вызвало это окно, не вызывается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `close()` закрывает окно, но при этом не удаляет содержимое этого окна. Т.е. если у тебя в окне была заполненная таблица, то после закрытия функцией `close()` ты всё ещё можешь обращаться к элементам таблицы.